# How to Multiply / Sum with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sum, multiplication

https://jsbin.com/wujusajowa/1/edit?html,js,output

I can sum the numbers of options. Like (5+5+5=15)

But I don't know a way to multiply the input with the sum of selects.

For example, What should I do to do **6 x** (5+5+5) and get 90 ?

Comment: Are you looking for the `*` operator?

Comment: `6 * sum` would be a guess

Comment: The `+` operator is for addition, and the `*` operator is for multiplication. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: _"I dont know how to get value from input"_ Current jsbin https://jsbin.com/wujusajowa/1/edit?html,js,output gets value from `<select>` elements as `sum`

Comment: @guest271314 from _text input_*, not _select input_. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<input type="number">`, define a global variable to store value of `<input>`; attach `change` event to `<input>` element to update global variable; use variable at `change` event of `<select>` element if variable is defined, else use `1` as multiplier

```
var input = 0;

$('select').change(function(){
 var sum = 0;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#toplam").html(sum * (input || 1));
}).change();

$("#miktar").on("change", function() {
  input = this.valueAsNumber;
});
```

jsbin https://jsbin.com/cujohisahi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much. But the sum still not increasing instantly. Is there a way to instant-increase?

Comment: @EfeÖztürk Use `input` event at `<input>` element, call `change` event inside `<input>` element event handler https://jsbin.com/tugizerunu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Comment: I have a one last question. I'm new with Javascript. How can I pass this "toplam" div to a PHP variable? @guest271314

Comment: _"How can I pass this "toplam" div to a PHP variable?"_ That is probably an entirely different Question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```js
var mySum = 6 * ( 5 + 5 + 5 );
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = mySum;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```